# Deriving covariance of joint distributions of MVN [Linear Gaussian systems?]

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, covariance, joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let $z$ ∈ R^L be an unknown vector of values, and $y$ ∈ R^D be some noisy measurement of z. We assume these variables are related by the following joint distribution

$p(z) \sim N(z|\mu_{z}, \Sigma_{z})  $

$p(y|z) \sim N(y|Wz + b, \Sigma_{y})$

where W is a matric of size D x L. This is an example of a linear Gaussian system.

The corresponding joint distribution, $p(z, y) = p(z)p(y|z)$, is a L + d dimensional Gaussian, with mean and variance given by
\begin{equation*}
\mu = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_{z} \newline
W\mu_{z} + b
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\Sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma_{z} & \Sigma_{z} W^\intercal \newline
W \Sigma_{z} & \Sigma_{y} + W \Sigma_{z} W^\intercal 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

This was what I was reading but I couldn't derive the variance matrix except for the obvious one at the top left corner.

Here's my lousy attempt:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Sigma_{12} & = & E[(z - E[z])(y - E[y])^\intercal] \newline
 & = & E[(z - E[z])(Wz + b - WE[z] - b)^\intercal ] \newline
 & = & E[(z - E[z])(W(z - E[z]))^\intercal ] \newline
 & = & E[(z - E[z])((z - E[z]))^\intercal W^\intercal ] \newline
 & = & E[(z - E[z])((z - E[z]))^\intercal] W^\intercal  \newline
 & = & \Sigma_{z} W^\intercal  \newline
\end{eqnarray*}

I'm very lost on this one.

1. Based on $ \mu_{2} = W\mu_{z} + b $ AND $\Sigma_{22} = \Sigma_{y} + W \Sigma_{z} W^\intercal $ , it feels like it is using $p(y|z)$ as a second element instead of $p(y)$. I'm very new to this and it puzzles me why that's the case, given that it is a joint distribution of z and y.
2. Is my attempt for $ \Sigma_{12} $ somewhat accurate or is it very wrong?
3. How can I derive $ \Sigma_{22} $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi: That looks okay to me for the $\Sigma_{12}$. Notice that the other covariance matrix, $\Sigma_{21}$, is the transpose of $\Sigma_{12}$ because covariance matrices are symmetric.

$\Sigma_{11}$ is the covariance matrix of $z$ because that's given.

Note that I'm using numbers to denote the ORIGINAL covariance matrices where $z$ is denoted by 1 and $y|z$ is denoted by 2. I just find that more natural.

Finally, you want, $\Sigma_{y}$, the  covariance matrix of the marginal of $y$.

We are implicitly given that $p(y|z) \sim N(Wz + b, \Sigma_{22})$.

Note that the assumption immediately above implies that (1) $y = Wz + b + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a D dimensional normal random vector which is $N(0, \Sigma_{22})$. Even though your original statement didn't include such a statement about $\epsilon$, $\Sigma_{22}$, the variance of $y|z$ can only exist due to the existence of some random noise vector attached to $y|z$.

So, given (1), we have $E(y) = W E(z) + b + 0 = W \mu_z + b$

Similarly, given (1), $\Sigma_{yy}= W var(z) W^{\prime} + var(b) + \Sigma_{22} = 
W \Sigma_{11} W^{\prime} + \Sigma_{22}$.

## ADDENDUM TO WHAT I WROTE ABOVE SO THAT NOTATION IS CLARIFIED:

I thought of it the following way:

In your "lousy attempt", you showed that $\Sigma_{12} = \Sigma_{zy} W^{\prime}$. All I did was turn everything around notationally so that in my notation, $\Sigma_{zy} = \Sigma_{12} W^{\prime}$.

\begin{equation*}
\Sigma_{(z, y|z)} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} \newline
\Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}  
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

In my notation, the matrix above denotes the covariance matrix of $z$ and $y|z$. From this, one is trying to obtain the covariance matrix of $z$ and $y$. This matrix is shown below.

\begin{equation*}
\Sigma_{(z,y)} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma_{zz} & \Sigma_{zy}  \newline
\Sigma_{yz} & \Sigma_{yy}  
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Of course, one can put in the relations using what we derived but , atleast for me, it's best to have the letters describe the marginals.

There's probably a simple and better way to distinguish so if someone wants to fix mine, it's appreciated. This is done all the time in the kalman filter but I can't recall how they notate so cleanly. If I did, I would have done it that way. Also, I'm not so good at latex which means  things that most others probably do in 1 minute, takes me 5 or whatever. I don't know the density of whatever but it's mean is greater than 1.

Also, I thought my distinction between raw covariance matrices versus calculated covariances was useful but maybe not. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! One question I had is, shouldn't we derive Σ22 = Σ + Σ11′ ? Seems we have Σ = Σ22 + Σ11′ here.

Comment: Hi Kevin JJ: My notation was probably confusing. The subscripts that are numbers denote the ORIGINAL covariances that are given. So, they are the covariances of z and y|z. The ones denoted with letters, $\Sigma_z$ and $\Sigma_y$, are the covariances of z and y. I hope that clarifies things so that  the formula for $\Sigma_y$ makes sense. What I am deriving are the formulae for your $\Sigma$.

Comment: Note that I reversed the notation and I probably shouldn't have. I wanted the derived covariances to have letters and the raw covariances  ( the given ones ) to have numbers.